# How to fix jarsigner issue used in command line windows giving "SocketException: Permission denied: connect"

Tags: java, windows, networking, command-line, jarsigner

I am trying to run the following `jarsigner` command:

```
jarsigner  -keystore C:/keystore.p12 -storepass  xyz  jars_to_be_signed.jar   friendly_name  -tsa http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp -storetype pkcs12  signedjar  C:/signed.jar
```

Without `timestamping` i.e. `-tsa option`, it gives signed jar properly. Hence signing is working.

But with `timestamping` i.e. `-tsa option` it gives the following error:

> jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

On hitting url http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp , I get the following output `Invalid Content-Type: <empty>`

It means port 80 is able to communicate.

I had previously enabled and then disabled Windows Firewall. Now, the Windows Firewall  is having  --  Windows Firewall state : off

And Kaspersky Security is also not having firewall enabled.

Port 80 in Listening ports is being used by system process. So Ive not killed these 2 processes on port 80.

What could be the reason for `SocketException: Permission denied: connect` ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the "SocketException: Permission denied: connect" problem by re-installing Kaspersky Security.
If anyone has this issue, check if firewall is blocking the connection to your pc.